# Android translate String

Tags: android, string

Im not programmer. Please help to add translation (Update now, New Update Available)  into string.xml.

```
public String getUpdateNowLabel() {
    return updateNowLabel != null? updateNowLabel : "Update now";


public String getTitle() {
    String defaultTitle = null;
    switch(mMode){
    case MODE_CHECK_VERSION:
        defaultTitle = "New Update Available";
        break;
    case MODE_ASK_FOR_RATE:
        defaultTitle = "Rate this app";
        break;
    }
    return title != null? title : defaultTitle;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can able to access string.xml value like this way
create a instance like this

WVersionManager ,this class not extending the activity so we need to give a context for accessing the resource

```
 Activity context;
    public WVersionManager(Activity act){
            this.activity = act;
            context=act;//do the context variable is global
            this.listener = new AlertDialogButtonListener();
            this.customTagHandler = new CustomTagHandler();
        }


 defaultTitle =context.getResources().getString(R.string.your_value);
```

Comment: The method getString(int) is undefined for the type WVersionManager

Comment: @PatrikRonaldz see that edited answer

Comment: full code https://www.dropbox.com/s/z672idk63fitah8/WVersionManager.java

Comment: use defaultTitle =act.getResources().getString(R.string.your_value);

Comment: i feel stupid))))) It does not work((  Can you write in what part of code i have to put Context context;

Comment: @PatrikRonaldz happy developing

Answer (score 2):

Add the strings to the corresponding strings.xml like this (create one for each language and place it on the corresponding folder like shown BELOW this post):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>
   <string name="update_available">New Update Available</string>
   <string name="rate_app">Rate this app</string>
   <string name="update_now">Update now</string>
  </resources>
```

and access the values like this:

```
public String getUpdateNowLabel() {
    return updateNowLabel != null? updateNowLabel : getString(R.string.update_now);


public String getTitle() {
    String defaultTitle = null;
    switch(mMode){
    case MODE_CHECK_VERSION:
        defaultTitle = getString(R.string.update_available);
        break;
    case MODE_ASK_FOR_RATE:
        defaultTitle = getString(R.string.rate_app);
        break;
    }
    return title != null? title : defaultTitle;
}
```

The string.xml file should be placed in the corresponding language folder..like this:

```
<project_root>/
    - res/
       - values/
         - strings.xml (default language eg. English)
       - values-pt/
         - strings.xml (portuguese language)
       - values-nl/
         - strings.xml (dutch language)
```

Comment: The method getString(int) is undefined for the type WVersionManager

Comment: getString(int) is a method available on Context class...Activity is a Context..so it also has it. If you're not putting this code in an Activity, then you have to perform the call of it with the reference of a Context...like: context.getString(int);

Comment: full code https://www.dropbox.com/s/z672idk63fitah8/WVersionManager.java

Comment: i see you have a 'Activity' field on it..so you can do like this: activity.getString(int)...Activity is a Context.